# Pattern type error in OCaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I am implementing my own version of lists in OCaml for a school project. It is defined as such :

```
type 'a my_list =
    | Item of ('a * 'a my_list)
    | Empty
;;
```

My goal is to implement 20 functions from the List module, and nth is giving me a lot of hard work. It is a recursive function which also calls hd and length funtions. Here is the code :

```
let rec length my_list =
    match my_list with
    | Empty -> 0
    | Item (hd, tl) -> (length tl) + 1
;;

let hd my_list = function
    | Empty -> raise (Failure "hd")
    | Item (hd, tl) -> hd
;;

let rec nth my_list n =
    let len = (length my_list) in
    match my_list with
    | lz when lz < 0 -> raise (Invalid_argument "nth")
    | sup when n > len - 1 -> raise (Failure "nth")
    | 0 -> (hd my_list)
    | _ -> (nth my_list (n - 1))
;;
```

On compilation I got this error :

```
$>ocamlc -w Aelz -warn-error A mylist.ml
File "mylist.ml", line 44, characters 10-11:
Error: This pattern matches values of type int
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type 'a my_list
```

Referring to the following line of nth: `| 0 -> (hd my_list)`

Any Ideas ?
Thank you

**EDIT 1**: Thank you everyone for your wiseful answers, here is the final code :

```
let rec nth my_list n =
    if n < 0 then raise (Invalid_argument "nth") else
    if my_list = Empty then raise (Failure "nth") else
    if n = 0 then hd my_list else nth (tl my_list) (n-1)
;;
```

**EDIT 2**: Thanks to your suggestions, this one is more strongly typed :

```
let rec nth my_list n =
    if n < 0 then raise (Invalid_argument "nth") else
            match my_list with
            | Empty -> raise (Failure "nth")
            | Item (hd, tl) -> if n=0 then hd else
                    nth tl (n-1)
;;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you match on `len` instead of `my_list`?

Comment: You are right, thank you !

Comment: Computing the length of the list is not the way to go: the length function requires a whole traversal of the list and you call it at every iteration of nth ! Have you counsidered a single traversal of the list with a counter somewhere, starting a 0 and you return the element at where you are when the counter reaches N?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I corrected it, thank you !

Comment: The symetric side-note of the one proposed by RichouHunter would be to prefer pattern-matching over non-basic types: Instead of `my_list = Empty then ... else if n=0 then hd my_list ... tl my list`, prefer using : `match my_list with Empty -> raise ... | Item (h,t) -> ...` where you can directly use `h` and `t` without going through `hd` and  `tl`.

Comment: @ghilesZ Should I do that even if I end with something like `Item (hd tl) -> if n=0 then hd my_list else ...` ?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to clarify that point. Thank you @ghilesZ for suggesting it. :)

Comment: Thank you @RichouHunter and ghillesZ, I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking the `nth` function. I'm not sure what you meant to do when writing it, but is the approach I'm thinking of:

- If `n` is negative, raise an error.
- If the list is empty, raise an error. You cannot get the `nth` element of an empty list.
- If the list isn't empty, see whether `n` equals 0.

  - If yes, return the head of the list.
  - If not, recurse.

---

Also, as a side-note, avoid pattern-matching on basic types. Instead of

```
match n with
| x when x<0 -> (* ... *)
| _ -> (* ... *)
```

prefer using `if`:

```
if n<0 then (* ... *) else (* ... *)
```

---

**EDIT**

On the other hand, when dealing with non-basic types, pattern-matching is strongly advised. So, instead of

```
if my_list = Empty then (* ... *) else (* ... *)
```

prefer the following

```
match my_list with
| Empty -> (* ... *)
| Item (hd, tl) -> (* ... *)
```

Furthermore (and I think this is what's causing you trouble with `nth`), you can combine both approaches:

```
if n < 0 then (* ... *)
else match my_list with
  | Empty -> (* ... *)
  | Item (hd, tl) -> (* ... *)
```

or

```
match my_list with
  | Empty -> (* ... *)
  | Item (hd, tl) -> if n < 0 then (* ... *) else (* ... *)
```

(*Hint*: The latter is probably what you need for `nth`.)

Of course, the type-checker is here to make sure that your types are consistent in your code.

Comment: I'm deliberately not giving you the solution, since you're learning OCaml. But know that OCaml is open-source, so if you're really stuck, you can peek at the code for the "real" `List.nth` function. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful advice :)

Comment: @bufferking As an exercise, you may also try with an option, either you return Some x, or None.

Comment: Agreed. The standard library has `List.nth_opt`, which does just that.

Comment: (For what it's worth, `List.nth_opt` is apparently coming in OCaml 4.05, which is not released yet as of this writing.)

Comment: Oh ok. I saw it while browsing the source code to check out the implementation of `List.nth`.